# Create function or constant Javascript inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I create a function within another?

I created a function that adds a loader, with two internal functions of SHOW and HIDE, how do I do it correctly?

Example function: loader.show() or loader.hide()

```
const loader = () => {
    show() {
        $('body').append('<div class="loader -puff" data-loader></div>');
    },
    hide() {
        $('[data-loader]').remove();
    };
}
```

Comment: `var loder = loader(); loder.show(); loder.hide();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `loader` an object, not a function.

```js
const loader = {
    show() {
        $('body').append('<div class="loader -puff" data-loader>loader</div>');
    },
    hide() {
        $('[data-loader]').remove();
    }
}

loader.show();
setTimeout(() => loader.hide(), 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```